# MySQL - how to use ENCLOSED BY in SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, select

I need Select query which will at the end write the result into the file.
I would like to have as output columns with double quotes separated, and I would like to have comma between the fields, but I am getting an error that query is not correct.

```
select hostname,ip 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
FROM TABLE1
```

As output I would like to get:

```
"hostname1","ip1"

"hostname2","ip2"
...........
```

Is this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -
 for reference, you can check [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html)

```
SELECT hostname,ip INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
   FROM test_table
```

Comment: Hi fa06 if I run the query on my Windows lap top with remote connection to the database using the MySql workbench I do not see where is my output file located? I wrote ".......INTO OUTFILE 'result.csv'......"  but I cannot find it although SELECT is succeful? Can you help me where is the file after the execution how to find it?

Comment: @Dejan, I think it stored in remote pc